# Linear maps on finite dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

So I am reading (or at least trying to get there) about spectral theory and the diagonalization problem.

To begin one considers how linear maps on finite dim spaces compare and relate. I am reading that of linear maps $T_i: V \to W $, they can be compared via

$$T_2U_2 = U_1T_1$$ for some invertible map $U_1: V \to W$ and $U_2: W \to V.$ This formulation suggests a square commutative diagram. IN other words, linear maps differed by an invertible map leads to the study of diagoalization.

Now my question is, why can't the relation be $T_1 = T_2 U_1$? And to get back $T_1$ we take the inverse of $U_1$.

Comment: Your question is very confused; probably you made some error(s) in typing it. The term linear _operator_ is reserved for a linear map from a vector space _to itself_, so you should not be writing $T_i:V\to W$. Moreover the composition $U_1T_1$ between two maps $V\to W$ cannot be formed. Probably you want to compare an operator $V\to V$ with an operator $W\to W$ using linear maps $V\to W$. This always involves a commuting diagram with _four_ arrows, though it makes most sense to require two parallel arrows $V\to W$ to be the same map. There is too much confusion to guess what might be meant.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen i forgot to change the title

Comment: Hint: Consider $$T_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, T_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Hawk: I was commenting on the body of the question, not the title (which by the way would need to be changed to say something about the actual question). You say you are comparing linear _operators_ $T_1,T_2:V\to W$, and that is not right. It is not meaningless to compare linear _maps_ $V\to W$, though I do not see how that would relate to spectral theory. Most likely you want to compare a linear operator $V\to V$ with a linear operator $W\to W$ (and that probably only when those spaces have the same dimension).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, no the only mistake was me accidentally using operators instead of maps.

Comment: No it was not. At the very least, as I commented, the composition $U_1T_1$ of two maps $V\to W$ makes no sense when $V$ and $W$ differ; one cannot apply $U_1$ to a vector produced by $T_1$. The same goes for the composition $T_2U_1$ that you want to compare to $T_1$ at the end of your question. Try to make a diagram of what you really want to ask about (making a diagram for what is written is not possible), and **edit the question** to match the labels in your diagram; then maybe we can figure out your question. As it stands I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $T_1,T_2:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by \begin{align}
T_1(x,y) &= (x,0)\\
T_2(x,y) &= (0,y),
\end{align}
with $x$ and $y$ nonzero. An invertible map $U_1:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is of the form 
$$U_1(x,y) = (ax+by, cx+dy), $$ with $ad-bc\ne0$. So for $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ we have $$T_2U_1(x,y) = T_2(ax+by,cx+dy) = (0, cx+dy), $$ which shows that $T_2U_1\ne T_1$.

Comment: You may be excused for not having understood the question, but whatever the question should have been, this is not the answer. If one thing is clear about the question is that is is about comparing maps on/between _different_ vector spaces.

Comment: I read nothing in the question to suggest that $V$ and $W$ could not be the same.